# Problems with Firefox gedit (default)

Tags: firefox

I'm new to Ubuntu so I not too familiar with this operating system yet. I'm trying to download a file off the internet using Firefox. Firefox ask what I want to open with and it is set as gedit (default) and I tried looking for Transmission to set that as my default but can't find it. I have transmission lock on my launcher but can't find it when trying to set as my default for opening files on Firefox. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

When you download the file, you can choose "Open with: 'choose'", where you have to select the executable file. It is in `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk`.
In the File Dialog, I think you have to click on "Filesystem" to get to the root folder (`/`)